# Linux kernel mutexes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel

I am reading "Linux device drivers 3rd edition", the chapter about concurrrency and race conditions. There is an example I don't completely understand; they are talking about the a common pattern in kernel programming, when one needs to initiate activity (fo rexample, new kernel thread or user process, request for existing process, or hardware based action) outside of the current thread, wait for that activity to complete. The example of not very effective solution is:

```
struct semaphore sem;
init_MUTEX_LOCKED(&sem);
start_external_task(&sem);
down(&sem);
```

Then they suggest the external task to call up(&sem) when its work is done.

I don't understand why can't we do it this way:

```
struct semaphore sem;
down(&sem);
start_external_task(&sem);
```

Why is is necessary to create mutex in locked state and then acquire the mutex after the task has been started?

Looking forward to hearing from you! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

When you call down(), your thread will block until another thread signals the semaphore. Since the other thread is not yet started, the thread will block indefinitely. That's why you need to start the thread first, and then call down() to block until the thread finishes.

If the thread finishes before you call down(), that's ok, because the semaphore will be signaled and down() will simply clear the signal and return.

Comment: +1, but I think would be better to use term `semaphore` instead of `mutex`. SEMAPHORE: could be up/down by any thread. MUTEX: has ownership, only lock owner thread can up the mutex. In this case we need to use semaphore, as it's purpose is communication between threads...

Comment: @Vojita: I agree. I used the term mutex because the question refers to the semaphore as a mutex.

Answer (score 3):

In first example down(&sem) will wait for external_task to call up(&sem) and effectively pause main thread until task completion.
In your code down() will lock main thread forever since there is no task yet to call up()

Answer (score 1):

The call:

```
init_MUTEX_LOCKED(&sem);
```

Creates a new semaphore in "mutex mode" initialised to 0. This means that a call to `down()` will block. A corresponding call:

```
init_MUTEX(&sem);
```

Would create a semaphore initialised to 1.

In the first example you initialise the semaphore to 0, you create your external_task and you call `down()` blocking until your task calls `up()`.

In the second example you don't initialise your semaphore, call `down()` blocking execution, and have no external_task running which can call `up()` to unblock you. The call to create external_task is thus never reached.

Incidentally, the process of initialising the semaphore with init_MUTEX_LOCKED has been removed in kernel version 2.6.37.